# Dual monitor with single motherboard (VGA and HDMI) black fews second when select "System Settings" in menu bar

Tags: display, monitor

I had single motherboard to use dual monitor WITHOUT additional graphic card. One monitor export VGA and another monitor export HDMI.

It perform normal but only when selecting "System Settings".

When selecting "system settings" through menu bar OR the setting icon at top right corner. The monitor with HDMI output would black screen for 2-3 seconds, then would resume normal.

The black screen situation is as same as "detect displays" in 'Systen Settings' -> 'Displays' -> 'Detect displays".

So far, I had confirmed that "About this Computer" and "Amazon" would also trigger the black screen flash.

This situation both exist in ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 14.10.

My motherboard is MSI-785GM-E65. And the Graphics info shown in "About this computer" is "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)".

### I had checked out the following method but still on luck.

### 1. unity-reset

### 2. changing the display resolution

Do anyone have advice for this situation?